# Querying on cassandra consumes CPU

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

Connecting to Cassandra from application code and querying consumes Cassandra's CPU.

My query is like :: `select fields from table where partition_key = "PARTITION_KEY" and clustering_key_1 = "KEY1" and clustering_key_2 in (a1, a2, a3..a100);`

I am using `in` keyword on clustering columns only. But it still afffects the CPU badly. Sometimes the CPU reaches 100%.

Is this normal ?

Answer (score 0):

No, 100% CPU usage is not normal for querying.  But quite frankly, neither is querying for 100 entries with an `IN` clause.

Even using `IN` on a clustering key forces Cassandra to perform *random* reads.  Cassandra was built for reading *sequentially*.  I would not recommend even double-digits of `IN` clause entries.

Recommendations:

- Try to keep the number of rows returned to a minimum.  You may need to break this query up into ten or twenty smaller queries.
- If you really just need 'a1' through 'a100', why not try it as a range query?

`select fields from table where partition_key = "PARTITION_KEY" and clustering_key_1 = "KEY1" and clustering_key_2 >= 'a1' and clustering_key_2 <= 'a100');`

Usually, 100% CPU during querying means that the cluster needs more nodes.  However, since the query is limited by partition, more nodes will not help.  In that case, the partitions might be too large, and re-modeling the table to have smaller partitions will spread out the load on the cluster more evenly.

**Edit 20200616**

There are other factors that can make a query consume high amounts of CPU.

Are you querying columns that support in-place writes or lots of deletes?  Both conditions will make Cassandra have to work harder, due to ignoring obsoleted and tombstoned data.

Try running an `iostat`.  If you're in a virtualized/cloud environment, you could be seeing "noisy neighbor" issues like CPU steal and high (disk) I/O wait times.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron. 
I have tried `select fields from table where partition_key = "PARTITION_KEY" and clustering_key_1 = "KEY1" and clustering_key_2 = "KEY2";`
But still the CPU performance is same.

In general should querying on cassandra (even at high rates like 500 queries per minute) consume CPU ? Couldn't find much info about read path consuming CPU.

Comment: @ShivaPrasad How much data is that query pulling back?  1k?  1mb?  10mb?

Comment: @ShivaPrasad run nodetool tablehistograms on this table: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsTablehistograms.html